# CMake not linking library on windows

Tags: windows, linker, cmake, mingw, sdl

### Introduction

I have a project which uses SDL2. The build system is cmake and I am attempting to get it to build on windows (which it needs to build on since this will be used chiefly on windows). On linux, it built on almost the first try. On windows, I've been struggling with this for the past 3 hours with no luck at all.

On linux, I just installed the SDL package, but on windows I am attempting to include a local copy. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like so:

```
include_directories(../include)

# Add libraries for linux
if(UNIX)
    enable_language(ASM)
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_check_modules(SDL_PKG sdl2)
    if(NOT SDL_PKG_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "No sdl found")
    endif()
    include_directories(${SDL_PKG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LIST(APPEND LIBS ${SDL_PKG_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# Add libraries for windows
if(WIN32)
    include_directories(../sdl-mingw/include/SDL2)
    LIST(APPEND LIBS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sdl-mingw/lib/libSDL2.a)
endif()

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wno-long-long")

set(SOURCES main.c paddles.c pong.c assets.S)
set_property(SOURCE assets.S PROPERTY LANGUAGE C)
add_executable(pong ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(pong ${LIBS})

install(TARGETS pong DESTINATION bin)
```

Upon building the project, I get the following output (scroll to the bottom for the exciting part):

```
-------------- Clean: all in pong (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 clean
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f src\CMakeFiles\pong.dir\build.make src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/clean
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
cd /d C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src && "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\pong.dir\cmake_clean.cmake
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
Cleaned "pong - all"

-------------- Build: all in pong (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Running command: C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f "C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build/Makefile"  VERBOSE=1 all
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong -BC:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\CMakeFiles C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f src\CMakeFiles\pong.dir\build.make src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\src C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src\CMakeFiles\pong.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f src\CMakeFiles\pong.dir\build.make src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\CMakeFiles 1
[ 33%] 
Building C object src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/main.c.obj
cd /d C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src && C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe   -Wall -Wno-long-long @CMakeFiles/pong.dir/includes_C.rsp   -o CMakeFiles\pong.dir\main.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\src\main.c
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\CMakeFiles 2
[ 66%] 
Building C object src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/paddles.c.obj
cd /d C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src && C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe   -Wall -Wno-long-long @CMakeFiles/pong.dir/includes_C.rsp   -o CMakeFiles\pong.dir\paddles.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\src\paddles.c
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\CMakeFiles 3
[100%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/pong.c.obj
cd /d C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src && C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe   -Wall -Wno-long-long @CMakeFiles/pong.dir/includes_C.rsp   -o CMakeFiles\pong.dir\pong.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\src\pong.c
Linking C executable pong.exe
cd /d C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\pong\build\src && "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\pong.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a
C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\pong.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe   -Wall -Wno-long-long   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o pong.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libpong.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\pong.dir\linklibs.rsp
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x4a3): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x4d0): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x52b): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x55b): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x58b): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderPresent'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x5b9): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x5c2): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x62c): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x66f): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x677): undefined reference to `assets_font_size'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x682): undefined reference to `assets_font'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x687): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromMem'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x695): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to `SDL_LoadBMP_RW'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x6e5): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x6f4): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x727): undefined reference to `SDL_FreeSurface'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x72c): undefined reference to `assets_sprites_size'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x737): undefined reference to `assets_sprites'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x73c): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromMem'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x74a): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x785): undefined reference to `SDL_LoadBMP_RW'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x79a): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x7a9): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x7dc): undefined reference to `SDL_FreeSurface'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x844): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyTexture'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x84f): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyRenderer'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x85a): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
CMakeFiles\pong.dir/objects.a(pong.c.obj):pong.c:(.text+0x85f): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [src/pong.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/pong.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/pong/build'
Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
37 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

The exciting part is all those undefined symbols. Most of them come from SDL, but some come from `assets.S` (which you can see [here](https://github.com/kcuzner/pong/blob/master/src/assets.S)).

### Question

Why does it appear that my `libSDL2.a` file is not being linked into the executable?

Also, why aren't the exported symbols from my `assets.S` file being seen by the linker as well?

I checked the `linklibs.rsp` file and it does indeed list `libSDL2.a`. If I change the name, make gets all upset, so I assume that means that the linker is reading the file. Normally I can figure out these sorts of problems, but I've made no progress at all on this.

**Dirty details**

CMake on Windows 8

CMake build configured for Code::Blocks using MinGW (the one installed with code::blocks)

SDL 2.0.3

The complete source is here: https://github.com/kcuzner/pong